# Node_redis hscan method pays no attention to the cursor position and to the COUNT parameter

Tags: node-redis

I'm trying to make some kind of pagination in my Redis service, so I think that cursor should work as an offset, and count as a count. 
I want to get two fields from my hash from the fourth position and I run this code:

```
        const promisedHscan = promisify(client.hscan).bind(client);
        hashContent = await promisedHscan("tasks", 3, "COUNT", "2");
```

And I get all the tasks stored in Redis started from the very beginning (from zero index);
Moreover, I can set any number for cursor value and count value and the result will be the same. (even 100 for both of them will work, but I have only 7 fields in my hash).

Can you help me to find out how this task can be done? I haven't found useful information in Redis documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that hscan doesn't work in this way and it doesn't fit for pagination purposes. 
My mistake was to treat cursor values as an ordered range of integer numbers. The cursor starts from 0, then it can be 12, or 15, or 28, then 3 and so on. That's why the order isn't guaranteed.